# How to submit a selected option into mysql with the same Button user pays with

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So I'm trying to make a online web shop and as a payment gateway I'm using securion. I would like to make the same button generated from securion also Insert the size selected in the dropdown into my mysql database.

I've tried this:

Connect to mysql and if I post submit it should insert the option into the database:

```
//Define your host here.
$hostname = "localhost";

//Define your database username here.
$username = "root";

//Define your database password here.
$password = "";

//Define your database name here.
$dbname = "ethereal";

 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username,$password);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $subject_names=$_POST['subject_names'];
    $sql = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO orders (size)
        values (:subject_names)");
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    $sql->execute(array(':subject_names'=>$subject_names));
    $conn->commit();
}


?>
```

Select options:

```
<option value="">Choose an option</option>
<option value="3cffe13b">Size S</option>
<option value="M">Size M</option>
<option value="L">Size L</option>
<option value="XL">Size XL</option>
</select>
```

The Buy now Button:

```
<form action="/your-payment-handler" method="post">



  <script src="https://securionpay.com/checkout.js"
    class="securionpay-button"
    data-key="pk_test_eb1OvVzqh3q8MkwvbgdTzxUf"
    data-checkout-request="OTEzYTViM2U4ZGNjNzUzZTc1NWEyYmRkOTQ0MWExOWM2MTQxZmI5OGNlNzA0NmNkYTc4ZjBkNDlhNjM0ODBlYXx7ImNoYXJnZSI6eyJhbW91bnQiOjUwMDAsImN1cnJlbmN5IjoiRVVSIn19"
    data-name="SecurionPay"
    data-description="Checkout example"
    data-checkout-button="Buy Now">
  </script>
</form>
</a>

<script>
function submit_form()
{
  document.form_name_here.submit();
}
</script>
```

My expected result is for it to open the securion pay window and simultaneously insert the size into the database.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` is the problem. They do not set that  Instead do `try {
    $charge = $gateway->createCharge($request);

    /* do something with charge object - see https://securionpay.com/docs/api#charge-object */
    $chargeId = $charge->getId();
   /* SAVE HERE */
} `

Comment: I am not that experienced on how to do that could you maybe leave an answer fully explaining it. It would really be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: No. Please consult the documentation. It is very clear. You need to insert into your DB in the place where the shopping basket has successfully been processed by them